# Three-wire USB type-C power delivery

Tags: usb, charger, usb-c, usb-pd

My HP Chromebook type-C charger stopped working after a hard pull on the cable. I tore apart the connector and found out the wires just beneath the connector were damaged. I got a new connector to fix them but am confused which wire to connect where.

Charging cable has 3 wires: white, blue, and black. The connector has 4 connection pads: G, D+, D-, and V, see attached image

I checked the voltage between all wires and got:

```
White - Blue = 2.9 V
White - Black = 0 V
Black - Blue = 2.9 V
```

Please help me determine which wire should be soldered to which pad.

[image]

Comment: Can you *do* Power Delivery with just three wires?

Comment: @Hearth I believe you can do USB-PD over 3 wires, but the third wire is not D+ or D- so this is a wrong connector. The third wire can be something else and USB-PD chip was in the old connector.

Comment: You need to cut open the metal shielding around the type c plug the part that actually goes inside the computer the chip is small but it's in there encased in clear silicone

Comment: That connector appears to have solder pads for only the USB 2.0 connection, this is not suitable for USB-PD.  With three wires in the cable is it possible to have ground, power, and communication lines, presumably with a chip in the USB-C plug performing the USB-PD negotiation and communicating by some serial protocol what has been negotiated.  Any repairs to the charger is likely to cost more than a new charger.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: None of the above, the HP has a chip inside the USB plug.

Perhaps something like Infineon [CYPD3177-24LQXQT](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/universal-serial-bus-usb-power-delivery-controller/usb-c-and-power-delivery/ez-pd-barrel-connector-replacement-bcr/cypd3177-24lqxqt/)
this chip interfaces with the client device and sends back a feedback signal to command the PSU to provide the correct voltage.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen. Is it a non-standard implementation? If so, will any other after market USB-C fast charger will be cable to charge this laptop? As far as I know all chargers deliver 5v in the beginning and then the device signals to the charger to send required voltage. I don't want to buy hp replacement charger because it's wire is too stiff and prone to damage.

Comment: it's a standard implementation, but there is a chip in the plug

Comment: I cut apart the connector but found no chip. Maybe it is inside the brick itself but it is not in connector.

Comment: that seems impossible.